# Text box value back to default if once focused and left empty

Tags: jquery

I want the text box to get its default value after focused and later left blank.

```
<input name="username" type="text" class="input username" value="Username"/>
<input name="password" type="password" class="input password" value="Password"/>
```

I tried with this script but not working

```
<input type="search" style="color:#858585" id="numbersearch" value="Search..." />
```

**Javascript code**-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var value = $("#numbersearch").val();
  $("#numbersearch").focus(function() {
    if(value == "Search...") {
      value="";
    }
  });

  $("#numbersearch").blur(function() {
    if(value == "") {
      value="Search...";
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only setting the `value` once, when the document loads. Additionally, when you assign to `value` you're only setting to the string variable, not the value of the element itself.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#numbersearch").focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "Search...") {
            $(this).val("");
        }
    });

    $("#numbersearch").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            $(this).val("Search...");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This was based on the OP's original question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original question (which you changed??) this answer should work for you...

http://jsfiddle.net/nDb5H/3/

Make sure you're referencing JQuery.js

```
<input type="text" style="color:#858585" id="numbersearch" value="Search..." />

//java script
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#numbersearch").focus(function() {
        if($("#numbersearch").val() == "Search...") {
            $("#numbersearch").val("");
        }
    });

    $("#numbersearch").blur(function() {
        if($("#numbersearch").val() == "") {
            $("#numbersearch").val("Search...");
        }
    });
});
```

A few notes: I'm assuming your input type should be "text" not "submit", also your val() should be called on each evaluation.